# div id naming structure and reference to CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am sorry because this is a basic question, I am new to CSS yet I need to get something done quickly so I was hoping for an espresso answer...

In my document I have divs that I want to name using the naming structure [category].[specificID] and they should all be subject to the [category] CSS definition.  E.g.

```
<div id="sectionTitle.experience">Experience</div>
...

<div id="sectionTitle.education">education</div>
```

I want the final ID to be distinct because I want to have the flexibility for separate JS handling.  But the formatting of each sectionTitle should be the same, hence the same CSS class.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your IDs must be unique to have valid HTML. Two elements cannot share the same ID, but they can share the same class name.

Also, I "think" you cannot have a `.` in your ID name, but I could be wrong about that.

What you want is:

```
<div id="experience" class="sectionTitle">Experience</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use IDs and classes. For example:

```
<div id="sectionTitle_experience" class="sectionTitle">Experience</div>
```

Note that I have replaced the `.` with a `_` to make it accessible in CSS - otherwise you'd have to resort to something like `[id='sectionTitle.experience']` instead of `#sectionTitle_experience`.

EDIT: That being said, if you want a quick-and-dirty fix, try this CSS:

```
[id^='sectionTitle.'] { /* styles here */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a css class .sectionTitle and have your desired styles into it. Pass this class to every div which will have your title text. So you can have same styles for header with different ids.